# mysql Create a Generated Column and Remove Specific Characters

Tags: mysql, concatenation, generated

I am creating a generated column using "concat", but i also need to have an "*" and "-" removed.  Can you do multiple functions when creating a generated column?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?

Comment: Try what, I don't know what function I would use, "replace"?  How do you put multiple functions in the generated field , a ','?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to nest the functions. Use the result of one function as parameter for the next one:

```
create table test (
  col1 varchar(50),
  col2 varchar(50),
  col3 varchar(100) as (replace(replace(concat(col1, col2), '*', ''), '-', ''))
);
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/KFAAO96832